# http get works in browser and postman but get a 401 using c# httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a web app hosted in azure. When I use postman to make the request I get a 
json result, which is the correcet response. When I try to make the same request via C# using the same token I receive a errpr - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

here is the code I use to make the request.

```
public string RequestData(string queryString, string token)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(queryString);
    request.Proxy = GetProxy();
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;
    request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = 0;
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    request.Headers.Add("authorization", "Bearer " + token);

    using (var webresponse = request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (webresponse.GetResponseStream() == Stream.Null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Response stream is empty");
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)webresponse;

        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I have double checked the token to ensure it is correct and it is. 
Another point I wanted to mention is that it did not work initially in
Postman without enabling Interceptor. This goes for Advanced Rest Client.
The request did not work until I enabled "XHR" and installed ARC cookie exchange.

I have checked the request headers in Fiddler and noticed there are no additional headers except for the authorization one (which I add as well).

**UPDATE:**

I got a successfull response in Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) 
and ran the code it generated for c# using RestSharp. In the response
the error thrown was

"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

Which points to the token not being correct. Which is confusing since it works
in Postman and Advanced Rest Client. Also I must mention I retrieve the token 
on each call using the clientid and secret using  the following code:

```
   public async static Task<AzureAccessToken> CreateOAuthAuthorizationToken(string clientId, string clientSecret, string resourceId, string tenantId)
        {
            AzureAccessToken token = null;
            var oauthUrl=string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/token", tenantId);       
            var reqBody = String.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}",clientId, clientSecret);                 
            var client = new HttpClient();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(reqBody);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(oauthUrl, content))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AzureAccessToken));
                    Stream json = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    token = (AzureAccessToken)serializer.ReadObject(json);
                    return token;
                }    
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, double checked it

Comment: In this case I believe that your proxy is blocking the request

Comment: I have tried setting the proxy as well. If i dont set the proxy i get an 407 error. I also get the same error when running it at home

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio, I think you are right about the token not being correct. Even if it worked in Postman and Advanced Rest Client. I have posted more code up on how I retrieve the token. Going to retrace my steps to make sure the correct token is being issued. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I recommend use Fiddler, then you can compare both requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking the log in azure, I saw the following error message:

JWT validation failed: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Did not match:  validationParameters.ValidAudience: 'f50a9d02-b8f4-408f-aaf8-0046e6cbf7a6' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'.

I resolved the issue by adding '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' to the "Allowed Token Audiences" under Azure Active Directory Settings.

Answer (score 0):

**I have called third party API. When I use postman to make the request I get a json result, which is the correct response. When I try to make the same request via C# using the same token I receive a error - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Finally I got the solution.**
When I make the login request some cookies will send by the server and that cookie will store in postman. If you see code snippet you will see information about request that is raised by postman.
When I call the Login method I stored the cookies like below:

```
public ResponseData OnGetResponseFromAPI(string URL, string Method, string PostData = null, Dictionary<string, string> Headers = null, string body = null, string ContentType = "application/json")
    {
            ResponseData response = new ResponseData();
            try
        {
                
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
            webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            webRequest.Method = Method;
            webRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
            if (Method == "GET")
            {
                var type = webRequest.GetType();
                var currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(webRequest);
                var methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
                methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);
            }
            if (Headers == null)
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> header in Headers)
            {
                webRequest.Headers.Add(header.Key, header.Value);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(PostData))
            {
                var RequestStream = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
                RequestStream.Write(PostData);
                RequestStream.Close();
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
            {
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                webRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream dataStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Close();
            }
            var ResponseStream = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());               
                string cookie = string.Empty;
                CookieCollection allCookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(webRequest.RequestUri);                
                foreach (Cookie c in  allCookies)
                {
                    cookie = cookie + c.Name + "=" + c.Value+";";                   
                }
                cookie = cookie.Substring(0, cookie.LastIndexOf(';'));
                var ResponseData = ResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
                response.response=ResponseData.ToString();
                response.cookie=cookie;
            return response;
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            if (webException == null || webException.Response == null)
                return null;
            var responseStream = webException.Response.GetResponseStream() as MemoryStream;
            if (responseStream == null)
                return null;
            var responseBytes = responseStream.ToArray();
            var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
            response.response = responseString;
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I am calling any api method I am sending token and cookie in header like below:

```
public string DownLoadDocument( string FilePath, string FileName, string token,string cookie)
        {
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

               
                HttpWebRequest webRequest;
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
                webRequest.Method = "GET";

                webRequest.ContentType = "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8";
                

                webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1";

                               
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Authentication", "Bearer "+token);
                webRequest.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
                                

                Stream responseReader = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();                


                using (var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    responseReader.CopyTo(fs);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }           
            return FilePath;
        }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30058803)

Comment: @JDOaktown: Why is that?

Comment: It is may be sufficient answer if any one face same issue which I had faced while calling third party api  calling from C# and in postman automatically add headers @JDOaktown:while calling which is required and please read every thing. In my third party api I missed cookies and if you any one face issue they can see code snippet  what they are missed for sending for authentication.